# Get data from inside array in Php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

With using of query i am getting result in array, i want to get this data in one array,
I am getting result like following way

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [full_name] => amit sharma
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [full_name] => amit
            )

)
```

I tried with following code but not working for me,Where i am wrong,Here is my code

```
$sql = "//select query";
$result= $this->db->query($sql)->result();
$total=count($result);
if($total>0)
{
    $data=array();
    foreach($result as $records)
    {
        $data[]=$records;
    }
    echo "<pre>";print_R($data);
}
```

Comment: WOuld be useful to see an example of the array you want to get to

Comment: you could use `result_array()` instead of `result()` then u will get query result as a pure array

Comment: Only the data? Because you can not have duplicate keys in an array.

Comment: ___but not working for me___ Do you mean it is crashing? Do you mean it is not generating the array you want? Remember we are not looking over your shoulder, we can only help if you give us enought information to be able to help

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile: if i go with result_array,then data is coming array inside array

Comment: Or do you just want to convert perfectly wonderful Objects into Arrays?

Comment: is it `print_R()` or `print_r()` does the uppercase `R` matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily loop it and get the values in array as below.

```
$post_id = array((object) (array(
   'id' => 1,
   'full_name' => "Amit Sharma",
)), (object) (array(
   'id' => 2,
   'full_name' => "Amit",
)), (object) (array(
   'id' => 3,
   'full_name' => "Amit Rohan",
)));

foreach ($post_id as $key => $value) 
{   $result[] = array("id"=>$value->id, "full_name"=>$value->full_name);    }

echo "<pre>";print_r($result);
```

Comment: @Arafind Bhat K: i want assosiative array not numeric/index

Comment: Updated my Answer please check. It should be working for you by now. @NidhiGupta

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

I have created same object as of your example, just ignore the code upto:

`$result = [$objOne, $objTwo];`

Use your `$result`

Json encode and decode it to get an associative array in return.

Code:

```
<?php
$objOne = new stdClass();
$objOne->id = 2;
$objOne->full_name = 'amit sharma';

$objTwo = new stdClass();
$objTwo->id = 1;
$objTwo->full_name = 'amit';

$result = [$objOne, $objTwo];
$arr = json_decode(json_encode($result), TRUE);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [full_name] => amit sharma
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [full_name] => amit
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [full_name] => amit sharma
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [full_name] => amit
        )

)
```